# How to do RFECV in scikit-learn with KFold, not StratifiedKFold?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedKFold, KFold
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV

rfecv = RFECV(estimator=LogisticRegression(), step=1, cv=StratifiedKFold(y, 10),
scoring='accuracy') 
rfecv.fit(X, y)
```

is an example to do RFECV with StratifiedKFold. The question is how to do RFECV with a normal KFold?

`cv=KFold(y, 10)` is not the answer since `KFold` and `StratifiedKFold` takes and returns a whole [different](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/model_selection.html#cross-validation-generators) values.

Comment: You are linking to very old documentation, the new one is here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/model_selection.html#cross-validation-generators have you actually read what you are linking to?

Comment: Accidentally pasted the wrong link because (fortunately) scikit has a stable API. I often read scikit 0.16 (current, yet) docs in PDF, and is still the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`KFold(len(y), n_folds = n_folds)` is the answer. So, for 10-fold it would be like

```
rfecv = RFECV(estimator=LogisticRegression(), step=1, cv=KFold(len(y),n_folds=10),
scoring='accuracy')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own CV strategy manually that mimics whatever `KFold` does:

```
def createCV():
    '''returns somthing like:

    custom_cv = [([0, 1, 2 ,3, 4, 5, 6], [7]), 
          ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6]), 
          ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5]),
          ([0, 1, 2, 3], [4]),
          ([0, 1, 2], [3])] 
    where the 0th list element in each tuple is the training set, and the second is the test 
    '''

manual_cv  = createCV()
rfecv = RFECV(estimator=LogisticRegression(), step=1, cv=manual_cv,
scoring='accuracy')
```

You could even use and rearrange what `KFold` would give you in `createCV` to suite your cv needs.

Comment: I'm so sorry but I figured it out. Thanks for your answer!